# Как убрать крякозябры из Qt приложения?

Tags: локализация, qt, c++

[image]

Comment: сама винда "русскоязычная"? или английская? Если английская, то нужно в настройках выставить киррилицу по умолчанию.

Comment: @KoVadim windows xp русская. это проблема именно Qt creator. если не верстать вручную, а ложить виджеты на готовую форму то проблем с русским языком нет. проблема только при верстке "вручную".

Comment: проверяйте кодировку исходного файла. Вполне возможно, что она "другая". Судя по коду, видна решила, что у Вас cp1250 или cp1252 вместо cp1251.

Также неплохо попробовать в utf8 сохранить файл.

У меня когда то подобные проблемы наблюдались в делфи и студии, если в настройках локали системы не выставлено кириллицу.

Comment: похоже, это проблема самой винды, т.к. аплет с настройками языков вообще не работает (не запускается), а с файлами проблем нет, они уже в utf-8 кодировке, я проверил. Вот он минус пиратских виндов.

Comment: запустил апплет, региональные настройки везде по умолчанию, русский язык выставлен, не знаю, на что теперь думать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Победил следующим образом:

1. Заходим Инструменты->Параметры->Текстовый редактор->По умолчанию->Кодировки файлов->По умолчанию - устанавливаем windows-1251
2. Добавляем заголовок `#include <QTextCodec>`
3. В самом начале функции main пишем следующее

   QTextCodec::setCodecForCStrings(QTextCodec::codecForName("CP1251")); 
       QTextCodec::setCodecForLocale(QTextCodec::codecForName("CP1251")); 
       QTextCodec::setCodecForTr(QTextCodec::codecForName("CP1251"));
4. все работает

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Доброго времени суток!

Ваше решение не самое лучшее - в Qt 5 оно не будет работать, поскольку в Qt 5 отсутствует статический метод `QTextCodec::setCodecForTr()` (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextcodec.html).

Разработчики Qt советуют перевести все исходные файлы проекта в кодировку UTF-8, и проблема исчезнет сама собой)

Успехов!

Comment: И не забывайте компилировать под Unicode-таргет (если под Qt есть разница).

Comment: опять минус ни за что поставили, говорю же, кодировка файлов в utf-8 на крякозяблы все равно есть, я проверял, а Qt 5 версии у меня не заработает на виндовс хр. Вот если переду на другую ос, то вопрос отпадет сам собой.

Answer (score 0):

Для Qt6 и проектов CMake простое элегантное решение:

1. Добавляем в конец файла CMakeLists.txt строку:

   ```
   set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY RULE_LAUNCH_COMPILE "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/decode.bat")
   ```
2. Помещаем текстовый файл decode.bat в папку, где лежит CMakeLists.txt с содержимым:

   ```
   @chcp 1251 >nul

   @call %*
   ```