# Как изменить свойства текста (шрифт и размер)

Tags: c++, qt

Записываю данные в файл (world ) в общем все нормально . Но мне надо записывать данные в файл с разными шрифтами и размером букв. К примеру, одна строка "Отчет" в размере 16 и шрифте oral, а другая строка "полученные результаты" в размере 12 и шрифте Calibri.

Мне посоветовали копать в сторону `QFont`, но там у меня получилось менять только характеристики виджетов, а не текста для отправки в файл.

```
//файл вывода (хотелось бы изменить шрифт и размеры строкам  strObrabotka0 , strObrabotka1)
QString strObrabotka0;
QString strObrabotka;
QString strObrabotka1;

//попытка дать строке другой шрифт
QFont Font("Times", 14, QFont::Bold);
QString text = tr( "GAME OVER" );
//-----------------------------------------------
strObrabotka0.append(QString("%1 %2 %3").arg("Время запуска программы ").arg(strObrabotka1).arg("\n"));
strObrabotka.append(QString("%1 %2").arg("  --------------------------------------------------------  ").arg("\n"));
strObrabotka.append(QString("%1 %2 %3 %4").arg("Коэффициент усиления ").arg(obm->stor->per_koef_usilen_2).arg("Дб").arg("\n"));
strObrabotka.append(QString("%1 %2 %3 %4").arg("Длительность излучаемого сигнала ").arg(obm->stor->per_dlina_izlych_signala).arg("Мс").arg("\n"));
strObrabotka.append(QString("%1 %2 %3 %4").arg("Период следования излучаемых импульсов ").arg(obm->stor->per_vrema_izlych_impuls).arg("С").arg("\n"));
strObrabotka.append(QString("%1 %2 %3 %4").arg("Рабочая частота ").arg(obm->stor->per_rabChastota_2).arg("кГц").arg("\n"));   
strObrabotka1.append(QString("%1 %2").arg("Обработанные данные лежат в документе win.xls ").arg("\n"));

// очиста файла перед работой
QFile file2("wivod.txt");
file2.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text);

// если сюда ввести (фаил закрыть) то но просто очистит документ
file2.close();
file2.open(QIODevice::Append | QIODevice::Text);

QTextStream out(&file2);
out.setCodec("UTF-8");
out << strObrabotka0;
out << strObrabotka;
out << strObrabotka1;
file2.close();
```

В общем сделал как вы и мне и по советовали

```
QTextEdit* ptxt = new QTextEdit("<em>текст</em> <strong>текст</strong> <b>текст</b><i>а этот - ещё и курсивным</i>");
QTextDocumentWriter writer;
writer.setFormat("odf");
writer.setFileName("wivodi.odf");

// writer.setCodec("UTF-8");
writer.write(ptxt->document());
```

НО в основном пишет всякую кракозябру. Как решить эту проблему ?

Answer (score 1):

Обычные текстовые файлы не поддерживают форматирование. Вы можете выводить форматированный текст в формате HTML, кроме того, Qt также [поддерживает формат ODF](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextdocumentwriter.html#supportedDocumentFormats).

Comment: я Пытался использовать HTML но он мне выводил кракозяблу ;_;

Comment: Можно примерчик пожалуйста

Comment: у меня были крякозяблы, вот этот вопрос http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/399631/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%8F%D0%B1%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%B8%D0%B7-qt-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F

Answer (score 0):

В общем вот ответ на мой вопрос но только , одну проблему я не решил это шрифт , почемуто он не восприменает команду  0_о

```
QString text = QObject::trUtf8("<p align=\"center\"> <font size=\"16\">Размер шрифта = 16</font></p> <br> <font size=\"25\" color=\"red\" face=\"Arial\"> <strong><em>Отчет</em></strong> </font> <br> <strong>текст</strong> <br> <b>текст</b><i>а этот - ещё и курсивным</i> ");

QTextDocumentWriter writer;
writer.setFormat("odf");
writer.setFileName("wivodi.odf");

QTextEdit *strin = new QTextEdit(text);

writer.write(strin->document());
```

Только он один раз записывает и если снова записать то "очистит " фаил и снова в него запишет , как " пополнять " фаил я не смог , а сделать большую строку у меня не вышло на append ругается при сборке