# Как правильно создавать QString c русским текстом

Tags: c++, qt

Не получается русский текст в документ ввести хотя при этом пробовал разные кодировки QTextCodec *codec = QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-8"); и QTextCodec *codec = QTextCodec::codecForName("Windows-1251"); .

```
//#include <QPaintDevice>
//#include <QPrinter>

 #include <QTextDocumentWriter>
 #include <QTextEdit>
 #include <QTextCodec>
 #include <QObject>

 MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
 {

 //    QString str = QObject::trUtf8("<p align=\"center\"> <font size=\"16\">Размер шрифта = 16</font></p> <br> <font size=\"25\" color=\"red\" face=\"Arial\"> <strong><em>Отчет</em></strong> </font> <br> <strong>текст</strong> <br> <b>текст</b><i>а этот - ещё и курсивным</i> ");
  //    QTextEdit *text = new QTextEdit(str);



 QTextEdit *text = new QTextEdit(" <HEAD> <TITLE>Пример простейшей таблицы</TITLE>  </HEAD>  <BODY> <TABLE BORDER> <TR><TD>Ячейка 1 строки 1</TD><TD>Ячейка 2 строки 1</TD></TR> <TR><TD>Ячейка 1 строки 2</TD> <TD>Ячейка 2 строки 2</TD></TR> </TABLE> </BODY> ");

QTextDocumentWriter writer;
writer.setFormat("ODF");
QTextCodec *codec = QTextCodec::codecForName("ANSII");
writer.setCodec(codec);
writer.setFileName("timob.odf");
writer.write(text->document());

ui->setupUi(this);
}
```

Строка QString str вообще не захотел отрываться документ ссылаясь на внутреннюю ошибку.

Не подскажете как сделать так что бы в фаил записывались русские буквы а не каракули ? Либо ссылку на С++ реализацию вдруг там можно работать с odf форматом (у меня Qt привязана к Microsoft Visual Studio 2010) .

```
 QTextDocument* doc = new QTextDocument(QStringLiteral("<HEAD> <TITLE>Пример простейшей таблицы</TITLE>  </HEAD>  <BODY> <TABLE BORDER> <TR><TD>Ячейка 1 строки 1</TD><TD>Ячейка 2 строки 1</TD></TR> <TR><TD>Ячейка 1 строки 2</TD> <TD>Ячейка 2 строки 2</TD></TR> </TABLE> </BODY>"));
QTextDocumentWriter writer;
writer.setFormat("ODF");
writer.setFileName("timob.odf");
writer.write(doc);
```

В общем QStringLiteral не оправдал надежд . Вот что он мне выдал :

```
  "<HEAD> <TITLE>РџСЂРёРјРµСЂ РїСЂРѕСЃС‚РµР№С€РµР№ С‚Р°Р±Р»РёС†С‹</TITLE>  </HEAD>  <BODY> <TABLE BORDER> <TR><TD>РЇС‡РµР№РєР° 1 СЃС‚СЂРѕРєРё 1</TD><TD>РЇС‡РµР№РєР° 2 СЃС‚СЂРѕРєРё 1</TD></TR> <TR><TD>РЇС‡РµР№РєР° 1 СЃС‚СЂРѕРєРё 2</TD> <TD>РЇС‡РµР№РєР° 2 СЃС‚СЂРѕРєРё 2</TD></TR> </TABLE> </BODY>"
```

Самое обидное что нет ни одной книги где было бы объяснение работы с "сложным текстом" (правильнее с "богатым текстом " но как то не по русски звучит ) .

Comment: Какая у вас версия Qt и ОС?

Comment: По умолчанию Visual Studio создаёт файлы в кодировке win-1251, но можно сохранить и в другой. [Тут написано](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18450459/how-to-determine-the-encoding-of-the-text-in-a-qtextedit-in-qt), что в контроле `QTextEdit` текст в кодировке **unicode**. У вас ведь проблема в том что текст зашитый в коде и переданный через контрол неправильно сохраняется в файл?

Comment: @perfect Qt 4.8 вижуал студио 2010 винда 7. Это первый комп . Qt 5.2 вижуал студио 2012 винда 8 второй комп .

Comment: @cybrex чисто русский текст в txt фаил без проблем. Но я хочу текст с таблицами и возможностью последующего редактирования , но с этим уже сложно . А все библиотеки которые нашёл , не все подключаються и в основном для чтения а не для записи "сложного  текста " в фаил

Comment: @timob256 посмотрите мой ответ несмотря на минус в карму я победил это только так http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/399631/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%8F%D0%B1%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%B8%D0%B7-qt-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F

Answer (score 6):

А. Чтобы получать `QString` c русским текстом я применяю следующую конструкцию:

```
QString russian_text = QString::fromUtf8 (u8"Русский текст");
QString russian_text = QString::fromUtf16( u"Русский текст");
```

Префиксы `u8` и `u` означают что строковый литерал закодирован в UTF-8 либо UTF-16, это требование стандарта. Есть и другие [префиксы](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) о которых, к сожалению, мало кто знает.

Б. Если префиксы `u8` и `u` не поддерживаются (как например в VisualStudio до версии 2015), то можно использовать другую конструкцию:

```
QString russian_text = QString::fromStdWString(std::wstring(L"Русский текст"));
```

В классе `QString` отсутствует конструктор вида `QString(const wchar_t *)`, поэтому чтобы не создавать лишние промежуточные `std::wstring`, под Visual C++, нужно использовать ту же статическую функцию `QString::fromUtf16`. Так как, напомню, что в Visual C++ "широкие" строки (`const wchar_t *`) имеют кодировку UTF-16. Поэтому под Visual C++ вот так тоже будет работать:

```
QString russian_text = QString::fromUtf16(L"Русский текст");
```

Однако не забывайте, что этот способ не переносимый. Например под GCC "широкие" строки могут быть закодированы по-другому.

Иногда под Visual C++ бывает, что линковщик не находит символ `QString::fromStdWString`, это происходит по причине того что Qt собрана с `wchar_t` как встроенным типом (конфигурация по-умолчанию), а проект-клиент собирается с опцией эмуляции `wchart_t` через `__int16` (ключ компилятора [/Zc::wchart-](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dh8che7s.aspx)). А так как `std::wstring` это на самом деле `typedef basic_string<wchar_t> wstring`, то получается что линковщик считает `std::wstring` из Qt и из проекта-клиента разными типами и не находит символ `QString::fromStdWString`. Решение, естественно, в том, чтобы привести опцию `/Zc::wchart` к единообразию во всех сборках.

В. Воспользоваться классом [QTextCodec](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtextcodec.html):

```
 QString russian(const char * text)
 {
    // подбираем нужную кодировку, другой вариант UTF8
    return QTextCode::codecForName("CP1251")->toUnicde(text);
 }
```

Comment: u8 не поддерживался в Visual Studio до 2015 версии

Comment: а как подключить к Qt Visual Studio  2015

Comment: @timob256 Вы наверно имели в виду наоборот "VisualStudio 2015 к Qt"? Это отдельный вопрос на который есть ответы в том числе и на этом ресурсе. Либо поясните.

Comment: @Cerbo Да "VisualStudio 2015 к Qt"

Comment: @timob256 дополнил ответ, может у вас эта проблема?

Comment: @Cerbo    конструкция 
        QString russian_text = QString::fromStdWString(std::wstring(L"Русский текст"));  превратилась в вот такой текст Р СѓСЃСЃРєРёР№ С‚РµРєСЃС‚

Comment: @timob256 еще дополнил

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас Qt5, я бы использовал `QStringLiteral` и сразу `QTextDocument`:

```
// Из вашего примера не совсем ясно, зачем вы создаете объект в куче, оставил как есть
QTextDocument* doc = new QTextDocument(QStringLiteral("<HEAD> <TITLE>Пример простейшей таблицы</TITLE>  </HEAD>  <BODY> <TABLE BORDER> <TR><TD>Ячейка 1 строки 1</TD><TD>Ячейка 2 строки 1</TD></TR> <TR><TD>Ячейка 1 строки 2</TD> <TD>Ячейка 2 строки 2</TD></TR> </TABLE> </BODY>"));
QTextDocumentWriter writer;
writer.setFormat("ODF");
writer.setFileName("timob.odf");
writer.write(doc);
```

По-умолчанию `QTextDocumentWriter` выводит текст в кодировке utf-8, поэтому нет необходимости указывать её явно.

Comment: Вобщем сделал как вы написали :3  и как всегда хрен ))))